# How to make a chatbot in Golang with dynamic plugins and adapters?

Tags: go, chatbot

I'm new to Golang and writing a chat bot as an exercise.

Basically I'm using net/http and gorilla/mux to handle requests.

For now it can only talk to one specific chat platform (I call it an adapter) and has only one plugin (find a picture on google).

How can I make both adapters and plugins be dynamic - so other developers can write their own stuff and just use my bot as a base platform? Are there any good examples?

Also should I have all the plugins and adapters in one repo/static binary or should they be separate? I know I can do both ways but what would you recommend as a better way to have easier collaboration and extensibility?

Comment: I started doing this as a side project but somewhat ended up abandoning it...but you can take a look to get an idea https://github.com/Tonkpils/grot

Answer (score 1):

[Medium post, "Standard Package Layout"](https://medium.com/@benbjohnson/standard-package-layout-7cdbc8391fc1), by Ben Johnson, helped me think about this.